# lightning component button doesnt fire

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, app-builder

I created a lightning component button I added them in to the page layout. I tried to do with the Lightning App Builder the button show up when I click nothing happens. The lightning component button is like below 
Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  controller="setCaseClose">
    <aura:attribute name="updateCase" type="Case" default="{'sobjectType':'Case'}"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Close Case" onclick="{!c.updateCaseClose}"  />
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    updateCaseClose : function(c, e, h) {
        h.updateCaseClose_helper(c,e,h);
    },
})
```

Helper

```
({
    updateCaseClose_helper : function(c,e,h) {
        var save_action = c.get("c.updateCheck");
        save_action.setParams({
            });
        $A.enqueueAction(save_action);
    }
})
```

Apex Class

```
public class setCaseClose {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateCheck(){
        list<Case> Case_list = new list<Case>();
        Case_list = [select id,Status from Case Limit 1];
        Case  p = new Case();
        p.id = Case_list[0].id;
        p.Status = 'Closed';
        update p;
    }
}
```

The button shows up in the page 
[image]

Clicking on it nothing happens, not what I am missing here.

Comment: This code is working fine, I guess you want to update the current Case but you are just querying a case and updating that, not sure which one.

Comment: To update the current Case pass the current case id to the Apex method and use that in the SOQL to retrieve that and update the same.

Comment: Can you help me how I can pass the CaseId from the component to ApexClass?

Comment: And also check the debug logs as you are not using any callback to check the response.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 Even though the field is updated now the page is not refreshed even after trying to add `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the helper to pass the parameter from JS to Apex.

**Helper:**

```
({
  updateCaseClose_helper : function(c,e,h) {
    var save_action = c.get("c.updateCheck");
    save_action.setParams({
      caseId: c.get('v.recordId')
    });
    save_action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(save_action);
  }
})
```

**Apex Controller:**

```
public class setCaseClose {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void updateCheck(String caseId){
    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
    for(Case case:[select id,Status from Case WHERE Id = :caseId]){
      case.Status = 'Closed';
      cases.add(case)
    }

    if(!cases.isEmpty()){
      update cases;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works now the records get the field updated but the page is not being refreshed Iadded `$A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();` in the helper after the `$A.enqueueAction(save_action);`

Comment: Or can you suggest me instead of using `$A.enqueueAction(save_action);` how I can use $A.getCallback()?

Comment: Try this, also updated in the answer above: save_action.setCallback(this, function(response) { $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire(); });

Comment: I am having issue when I have two buttons, can you please help with this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301425/lightning-component-buttons-are-not-working-as-expected